# Disable font colour formatting for negetive values in python Polars generated excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars

I would like to disable automatic font colouring of negetive values in polars `write_excel`. Any tip?

```
import polars as pl
import xlsxwriter

df2 = pl.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(-10, 10, 5*3).reshape(-1, 3), schema=['x', 'y', 'z'])

with xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'_out_.xlsx') as workbook:
    df2.write_excel(workbook=workbook, worksheet='sheet1',
                    autofit=True, table_style=None, column_formats=None,
                    conditional_formats=False, float_precision=0, sparklines=None, formulas=None)
```

This is what it generates -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`column_formats={cs.numeric():'General'}` or `column_formats={x:'[Black]' for x in df2.columns}` will do the trick.

```
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
import polars.selectors as cs
import xlsxwriter

df2 = pl.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(-10, 10, 5*3).reshape(-1, 3), schema=['x', 'y', 'z'])

with xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'C:\SUVOPAM_local\Try\_out_.xlsx') as workbook:
    df2.write_excel(workbook=workbook, worksheet='sheet1',
                    autofit=True, table_style=None,  dtype_formats=None,
                    column_formats={cs.numeric():'General'}, # column_formats={x:'[Black]' for x in df2.columns}
                    conditional_formats=False, float_precision=0, sparklines=None, formulas=None)
```

Generates -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the dtype_formats to General (or whatever you like, see below)

for example

```
with xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'_out_.xlsx') as workbook:
    df.write_excel(workbook=workbook, worksheet='sheet1',
                    autofit=True, table_style=None, column_formats=None, 
                    dtype_formats={pl.Int64():'General'},
                    conditional_formats=False, float_precision=0, sparklines=None, formulas=None)
```

<s>Instead of `pl.Int64` you could use [`cs.numeric`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html#polars.selectors.numeric) if you prefer that to be the case for all numbers.</s>

I mistakenly thought you could have `cs.numeric` in place of pl.Int64() but it is a column selector not dtype selector. Instead you'd use that in the column_formats and leave dtype_formats unset.

Additionally, it seems that not all versions of Excel interpret 'General' the same as mine

If you want something else, one trick is to go into Excel's Format Cells window, pick what you want through the Categories, for instance:

[image]

then click on the Custom category:

[image]

and copy what it autogenerates in Type.

```
with xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'_out_.xlsx') as workbook:
    df.write_excel(workbook=workbook, worksheet='sheet1',
              autofit=True, table_style=None, 
              column_formats={cs.numeric():'0.0000000_);(0.0000000)'},
              conditional_formats=False, float_precision=0, sparklines=None, formulas=None)
```

Comment: Hi, still the negative values are in red.

Comment: I just double checked it and with your code they're red and with mine they're black. My code uses `df` rather than `df2` though. Are you saving a different `df` that has number types in addition to Int64 without using the cs.numeric in place of Int64?

Comment: Using the original `df2`, just added `dtype_formats={pl.Int64():'General'}`, rest are same. Using Office365.

Comment: using polars 0.19.2

Comment: found a crude way `column_formats={x:'[Black]' for x in df2.columns}`. Could you please add a snippet how to use `cs.numeric` ?

Comment: Something like - `import polars.selectors as cs` and then add `dtype_formats={cs.numeric(): 'General'}`? which doesn't work in my case :)

Comment: @betagreen see my latest edit. I was mistaken but the correction is pretty easy.

Comment: `column_formats={cs.numeric():'General'}` should work too and probably the easiest. Please add an alternative answer, and I would accept it gladly :)

Comment: and the above method is independent of excel version.