# Coloring rows of dataframe in excel using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter, python-polars

Here is my code, my problem seems to be writing the dataframe to excel creates formatting that I cannot overwrite:

```
import polars as pl
import xlsxwriter as writer

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 2, 3, 2, 5],
    "B": ["x", "y", "x", "z", "y"]
})

with writer.Workbook('text_book.xlsx') as wb:
    worksheet = wb.add_worksheet()
    data_format1 = wb.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE'})
    df.write_excel(wb, worksheet = 'Sheet1', autofilter= False,
                         autofit = True, position = 'A3', include_header = False)
    for row in range(0,10,2):
        worksheet.set_row(row+2, cell_format=data_format1)
```

Output:

[image]

Ideally the ouput would be:

[image]

I'm looking for a method of iterating over some list of row indices and setting the color for those rows.

Comment: Not a full answer, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098444/disable-font-colour-formatting-for-negetive-values-in-python-polars-generated-ex) question seems related.

Comment: @Hericks This seems more about changing the formatting of an entire column where as I'm looking to iterate over the rows and change row formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that your sample code doesn't work as expected is that Polars `write_excel()` applies a cell format for numbers and that overwrites the row format.

You can control column or dtype formatting via the [`write_excel()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.write_excel.html#polars.DataFrame.write_excel) APIs but that won't give you row by row control. A better way to achieve what you are looking for is by setting a table style property for the output dataframe.

Polars exports dataframes as a worksheet table (see [XlsxWriter](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.write_excel.html#polars.DataFrame.write_excel) docs) so you can specify the table style like this:

```py
mport polars as pl
import xlsxwriter as writer

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 2, 3, 2, 5],
    "B": ["x", "y", "x", "z", "y"]
})

with writer.Workbook("text_book.xlsx") as wb:
    worksheet = wb.add_worksheet()
    df.write_excel(
        wb,
        worksheet="Sheet1",
        autofilter=False,
        autofit=True,
        position="A3",
        include_header=False,
        table_style="Table Style Medium 3",
    )
```

Which gives an output like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think I've found a solution by just converting to a pandas dataframe.